# Microsoft Graph API group folder invite response is wrong

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to grant a single user (possibly outside of the organization) access to a folder used by a shared group in Share Point [The Microsoft Graph Docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_invite) state that the response should have an Id in it.

If I use a personal oneDrive account, and make the following request:

`POST v1.0 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{folderId}/invite`

```
body: {
    "requireSignIn": true,
    "sendInvitation": true,
    "roles": [ "read"],
    "recipients": [
      { "email": "{myPersonalEmail}" },
    ],
    "message": "testing giving permission to self"
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
            "id": "{permissionID}",
            "roles": [
                "read"
            ],
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "{myPersonalEmail}",
                    "id": "{responseID}",
                    "displayName": "Sarah"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, we setup a different SharePoint account that when I make the same request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{folderId}/invite`
I get a completely different response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(permission)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.permission",
            "roles": [
                "read"
            ],
            "invitation": {
                "signInRequired": true
            },
            "link": {
                "type": "view",
                "webUrl": "{shareURL}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is so bizarre to me, because we are hitting the same endpoint. It makes me think that maybe there are some site configurations that are making these two responses differ.

Does anyone know why we would be getting a different results from the same endpoint?

Comment: Because you have create a invite url for the share folder when you setup a different SharePoint Account.

Comment: hmm I am not sure I understand, could you explain a little more? Someone else set everything up. I'm not very familiar with it all.